# What makes Checkinstall packages not suitable for distribution?

Tags: apt, package-management, packaging, checkinstall

I am planning to have multiple servers running with the same packages. And as a solution to not compile packages individually on each server, I want to use [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) to generate .deb and then distribute it via private repository.

However, in the linked guide it says that it is

> not designed to produce packages suitable for distribution

My questions are:

1. What is different about this packaging, that makes it not suitable for distribution? Or what should be in the package, to make it suitable?
2. Could there be any issues with using checkinstall and distributing packages to ~20 servers?

Any advice or links where I can find out more appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packages created by checkinstall often don't meet the standards for packages. This may cause problems if you distribute a package to other people. But there's nothing wrong if you use them on multiple of your own systems if they work for you.

For example packages created by checkinstall usually don't contain dependency information so they may not work until you manually install some additional packages.

Some files may be placed in a wrong location, have a wrong name or reference files with a wrong location or wrong name. They may for example not work with they way Debian and Ubuntu handle the Apache configuration or the system startup without some additional work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. Indeed the packages didn't handle any dependencies and I had to manually install.